# Why use specific vendor prefixes instead of one representing all browsers?

Tags: css, vendor-prefix

As far as I know, the only reason behind usage of vendor prefixes is that they were introduced by browser creators to release a new specification before it's completely implemented according to W3C.

But why do we need a specific vendor prefix for every browser?

If we look at the following CSS,

```
.box{
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
   -o-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
   box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}
```

why can't this be written like the following?

```
.box{
   -vendor-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
   box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}
```

Each individual browser, on seeing the prefix `-vendor-`, implements it in its own way.

This not only makes it easy for developers, but also for browser creators as situations like Microsoft and [Opera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_%28web_browser%29) compromised started supporting `-webkit-` because developers were lazy to use `-ms-` and `-o-` would never rise. If it was the case with `-vendor-` it applies to every browser.

What is the explanation?

Comment: Interesting question. I think the answer might be that if you did a generic vendor prefix you could ask the following question, `"why vendor prefixes at all?"` Wouldn't `-vendor-` be equal to a non vendor version? The prefix allows each browser vendor to do their own thing.

Comment: @hungerstar u need a distiction between an implementation of W3C specification and browsers own implementation. but having individual prefix is what i am debating upon

Comment: If one vendor did this: `box-shadow( offsetx, offsety, blur, radius) ` and another this: `box-shadow( blur, radius, offsetx, offsety )` how would you set the parameters to use `-vendor-box-shadow` so both browsers would understand the property?

Comment: @hungerstar if same parameters are used why do browsers change the order why cant they implement in the same way. By not implementing W3C spec it means not using the same algo is fine why change parameters.That hinders developers right

Comment: I think that's the whole point of the prefix, you can do your own thing until it's standardized (if ever). You don't have to wait around for the W3C to tell you what to do. Maybe I'm not picking up what you're putting down.

Comment: Closing because the asker seems intent on pushing their own agenda. I'll leave my factual answer up for the sake of posterity.

Answer (score 14):

> As far as I know the only reason behind usage of vendor prefixes is that they were introduced by browser creators to release a new specification before its completely implemented according to W3C

No; *according to W3C*, the purpose of a vendor prefix is for a vendor to provide their own implementation of an experimental, proprietary, or otherwise non-standard feature. The prefix is meant to identify the specific vendor responsible for this implementation. From the [CSS2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#vendor-keywords):

> In CSS, identifiers may begin with '-' (dash) or '_' (underscore). Keywords and property names beginning with -' or '_' are reserved for vendor-specific extensions. Such vendor-specific extensions should have one of the following formats:
>
> ```
> '-' + vendor identifier + '-' + meaningful name
> '_' + vendor identifier + '-' + meaningful name
> ```
>
> For example, if XYZ organization added a property to describe the color of the border on the East side of the display, they might call it -xyz-border-east-color.

In fact, the spec doesn't even specifically mention "experimental implementations of existing or pending standards", although that just falls under the category of "non-standard" anyway.

Furthermore, because a vendor can implement their own property *however they like*, you cannot guarantee that every vendor will agree upon something as simple as the syntax of a property. For example, the longhand properties for `border-radius` looked like this in Firefox:

```
-moz-border-radius-topleft
-moz-border-radius-topright
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft
```

Which is very different from WebKit:

```
-webkit-border-top-left-radius
-webkit-border-top-right-radius
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius
```

As you can guess, the WebKit form was the one that made it to the final spec, which Mozilla had to follow when they got around to promoting `border-radius` to standard in Firefox 4. But here's the kicker: the reason Mozilla originally implemented the longhands with the old names is because [once upon a time, those were the names that were used by the *spec*](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/WD-css3-box-20010726/#border-radius)! So it wasn't just WebKit that renamed the properties, but the CSSWG as well, which ultimately led to an incompatibility between implementations.

There isn't much of a point in having a single prefix for all experimental implementations, because then you might as well just have everyone implement the property without the prefix and save having to needlessly duplicate it or "unprefix" it later. And even then, you still have the aforementioned problem of evolving standards and implementation incompatibilities.

The problem with WebKit prefixes simply stems from a widespread abuse of prefixes by both vendors and authors (mostly with authors choosing to only use `-webkit-` and ignoring others thanks to the popularity of Chrome and whatnot). Browser vendors have found a much better way to deal with this which allows them to [abandon prefixes altogether](http://www.chromium.org/blink#vendor-prefixes), such as hiding experimental properties behind compatibility flags in their UI.

Note that prefixes are still used for their original intended purpose; for example Microsoft uses `-ms-` for CSS implementations of various WinRT components, and Mozilla uses `-moz-` for CSS implementations of XUL, which is used to implement Firefox's UI.

Comment: ok now i know that W3C has recommended specific prefixes.
so lets pitch to W3C that if a single prefix representing all non-W3C implementations can be used then change it in the next version of css.
ultimately all matters is application of css rules shouldnt alter output

Comment: no, prefixes are required because if a spec hasnt come from W3C but from the vendor itself like the experimental features of chrome are released using -webkit- prefix they have no option to distinguish it from the properties defined in W3C spec if they dont use predix. so they are required.

Comment: "application of css rules shouldnt alter output" See, the problem is that the very nature of experimental implementations is that you can't guarantee that an implementation, if one exists, will conform to the standard, and that's assuming a standard even exists.

Answer (score 3):

Vendor prefixes are not implemented the same way. Some of them take different parameters or in different order, such as gradients. In that case you won't be able to write a general -vendor-gradient because they don't take the same parameters.

In the list of vendor prefixes you have,

- Android: -webkit-
- Chrome: -webkit-
- Firefox: -moz-
- Internet Explorer: -ms-
- iOS: -webkit-
- Opera: -o-
- Safari: -webkit-

I used a gradient generator and the output was this for some specific gradient

```
background: #1e5799; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1E5799 0%, #2989D8 50%, #207CCA 51%, #7DB9E8 100%); /* Firefox 3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #1E5799), color-stop(50%, #2989D8), color-stop(51%, #207CCA), color-stop(100%, #7DB9E8)); /* Chrome and Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1E5799 0%, #2989D8 50%, #207CCA 51%, #7DB9E8 100%); /* Chrome 10+ and Safari 5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #1E5799 0%, #2989D8 50%, #207CCA 51%, #7DB9E8 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #1E5799 0%, #2989D8 50%, #207CCA 51%, #7DB9E8 100%); /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #1E5799 0%, #2989D8 50%, #207CCA 51%, #7DB9E8 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1E5799', endColorstr='#7DB9E8', GradientType=0 ); /* Internet Explorer 6-9 */
```

You can see that parameters are different. Another example I remember is content justify when I used flex elements:

```
justify-content: space-between;
-moz-justify-content: space-between;
-ms-flex-pack: justify;
-webkit-justify-content: space-between;
```

There you can see that for the -ms- vendor parameter and property is different to achieve the same result.

Vendors have their own different implementation, so they can't be generalized.

Comment: can u specify a case where the parameters are in different order. Please list as many cases u know. I really want to be enlightened on this topic

Comment: Alright no problem, I know gradient because I used that before, I hardly remember other ones but I will try :D

Comment: in your examples notice that if two property names are exactly identical apart from the prefix their parameters are same. -webkit-gradient and -webkit-linear-gradient are two different things name wise but output is same, similarly justify-content, flex-pack are different names

Comment: You have -ms-flex-pack but you don't have -ms-justify-content, there you see implementations are drastically different. I guess you won't accept an answer here, you are not making a question, you are just giving your point of view.

Comment: @Carlos Calla: I knew I should have just closed the question instead of trying to answer with facts. Don't mind if I do.

Comment: @BoltClock : no problem, go ahead.