# Why do I need so much code for a simple CSS gradient?

Tags: css

I'm just kind of curious as to why I need so many different lines of CSS code to make my gradient compatible with most browsers. Isn't this something that should be universal?

Correct me if I'm wrong, but if something this simple is this not universal, I'm surprised that we don't need browser specific code for font-size, padding, margin, etc.

```css
div.myQuestion {
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #7d7e7d;
    /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #7d7e7d 0%, #0e0e0e 100%);
    /* FF3.6-15 */    
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #7d7e7d 0%, #0e0e0e 100%);
    /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */    
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #7d7e7d 0%, #0e0e0e 100%);
    /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */    
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#7d7e7d', endColorstr='#0e0e0e', GradientType=0);
    /* IE6-9 */
}
```

```html
<div class="myQuestion"></div>
```

Comment: It is called history

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why use specific vendor prefixes instead of one representing all browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25431595/why-use-specific-vendor-prefixes-instead-of-one-representing-all-browsers)

Comment: BTW, the old webkit syntax is missing: `-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#7d7e7d), color-stop(100%,#0e0e0e))`, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because gradients are complicated.

You don't need prefixes for padding and margin because they were defined in CSS 2.1, and are simple enough.

However, gradients were defined much later, in CSS3. Moreover, the syntax changed multiple times. The behavior also changed. Some people were still arguing relatively recently to change the space of colors in which the color stops are interpolated (it's not obvious when you take transparency into account).

Then, lots of people don't update they browsers. So they are stuck with these preliminary implementations.

Now most browsers have realized vendor prefixes are a nightmare and they decided to avoid using them for new properties.

Comment: So possibly in the future there will be a "defined" gradient syntax?

Comment: @r553 `linear-gradient(to bottom, #7d7e7d, #0e0e0e)` is one of the proper syntax. It should be enough for compliant browsers. But won't work on old browsers.